# How do I convert my timedelta64 minute values back to regular time?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, time, timedelta

```py
#Convert dftime Into TimeDelta
df_time_delt = pd.to_timedelta(dftime.astype(str)).astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

After I get my `timedelta` values in minutes, how do I convert the values back to the time values of `00:00:00`?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant method is [dt.normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```py
normal_time = pd.to_timedate(dftime.astype(str)).dt.normalize()
```

Comment: I get an error. "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". The time values are in a np.series. I assume your algo is only reading this as an object and not a datetime datatype?